# Big Mysql Query (Join counts in the result and modify a string)

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am brand new to mysql so please excuse my level of knowledge here, and feel free to direct me in a better direction if what I am doing is out of date.

I am pulling information from a database to fill in a php page.

My tables:

Server:

```
|ServerID (int) | ArticleID (int) | locationID (int) |
|   1           |       46        | 55               |
|   2           |       11        | 81               |
|   3           |       81        | 46               |
|   4           |       55        | 11               |
|   5           |       81        | 99               |
|   5           |       11        | 52               |
```

Article:

```
|ArticleID (int)  | Name (varchar)  | Typ (int) |
|   46            |   domain        | 0         |
|   81            |   root-server   | 1         |
|   55            |   vserver       | 2         |
|   11            |   root-server2  | 1         |
```

Location:

```
|LocationID (int) | location (varchar) | 
|   46            | 1-5-15-2           |
|   81            | 1-5-14-2           |
|   55            | 2-25-1-9           |
|   11            | 21-2-5-8           |
|   99            | 17-2-5-8           |
|   52            | 1-8-5-8            |
```

Result:

```
|location (int) | name (varchar) | count (int) |
| 1             | root-server    | 1           |
| 1             | root-server2   | 2           |
| 17            | root-server    | 1           |
```

The location in the result is the first number block of the location in the location table (1-5-15-2 -> 1, 1-8-5-8 -> 1, 21-2-5-8 -> 21, 17-2-5-8 -> 17). 
The count is the sum of all servers with the same name and the same first location block.

Do anyone think its possible to get this result in only one query?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: are there more items in each of those tables? looks like you have foreignkeys as primary keys ? what is type? and why isn't it in the results? also, why is location in results 1 1 17, that doesn't exist in your example

Comment: @naturalc Yes there are more items in each of those tables. The server table has 20000 items and the article table 500. Witch type? The location  in the result is the first block of the location in the location table. (1-5-15-2 -> 1, 1-8-5-8 -> 1, 21-2-5-8 -> 21, 17-2-5-8 -> 17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, '-', 1) as LID,Article.Name,Count(*) as Count 
from Location join Server  
on Server.locationID=Location.locationID  
join Article on Article.ArticleID=Server.ArticleID
group by LID,Article.ArticleID  ;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cd922/14)

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a shot:

```
SELECT 
    s.locationID as id, a.name, count(*) as count
FROM
    `Server` s
    LEFT JOIN
    `Article` a ON s.ArticleID = a.ArticleID
GROUP BY s.locationID, a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
select 
    s.location_id as location, a.name, count(location) as count 
from 
    server as s, article as a 
where 
    s.articleID = a.articleID 
group by location, a.name
```